# L'Hopitas Rule, rewriting $(8+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I evaluated the correct answers for the limit with the function $(8+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ using a different method, but I do understand how L'Hopitals works, its just rewriting this function into $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ I am very confused about. I am able to do so with other functions such as $x\ln(x)$, but I am not sure how to do so with an exponent.

Comment: What is the limit? Are we approaching zero? infinity? please edit your post to include more information.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Rewrite $(8+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ as $e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(8+x)}$.

So $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} (8+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ becomes $e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\ln(8+x)}$

Now apply L'Hospitals Rule in the exponent.

Comment: I don't think for the $x \to 0$ case, L'Hospitals Rule can be applied, because the exponent is not in indeterminate form.

Comment: @AritraDas Valid point. Edited

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes much more sense to me!!

Comment: @bedtime21 You're welcome. BTW if you like the answer, you can accept it by clicking the tick mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\lim (8+x)^{1/x}=L$$

Take logs:

$$\lim \frac{\log(8+x)}{x}=\log L$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your limit is (I'll edit this once you specify in the comments), but we can rewrite any $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)^{\frac{1}{g(x)}}$ as $\lim_{x \to c} e^{\frac{1}{g(x)}\ln f(x)} = e^{\lim_{x \to c} \frac{\ln f(x)}{g(x)}} = e^{\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f'(x)}{g(x)f(x)}}$ As long as the conditions for L'Hopital's rule are met